# Using optim in R, how would I maximize a function of several variables given a few of them?

Tags: r, optimization, conditional-statements, maximize

I have a function of four variables, (c,l,t,a)

I only want to optimize this function over c and l, because a and t are inputs and are used inside the function, sometimes for indexing and stuff. (Which is why I cannot just take the 1st order condition, set equal to zero, etc...).

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

Ok so I think the problem might be the way I am using optim sort of.  I am going to try something and reframe my q.

Comment: Could you post the function you are trying to pass to optim, an example of how you are implementing optim, and any error messages you are receiving?

Comment: Your system is underdefined and in all likelihood has an optimum plane `g(c,I)` .  You cannot optimize without another constraint.

Comment: To carl:  I have an upper and lower bound for c and l

Comment: To Joe:  The function is kind of complicated, but I'll try posting a simple idea of what I'm doing above

Comment: An upper bound is unlikely to be sufficient.  From basic algebra, if you want to solve for N variables, you need N independent equations.

Comment: Hi Carl,   If I say, Max f(x,y) s.t. x>0 x<M, y>0, y<Z....then the upper bound constraint is (M,Z) and the lb is (0,0).  Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a function of four parameters:

```
> foo=function(c,l,t,a){c+10*l+100*t+1000*a}
> foo(1,2,3,4)
[1] 4321
```

You only want to optimise over two, so make a function of two parameters and call the four-parameter function with the other parameters set:

```
> f2=function(c,l){foo(c,l,9,8)}
> f2(1,2)
[1] 8921
```

Now whatever you were doing with `foo` you do with `f2`.

If you want you can create a function-generating function that returns functions with the fixed parameters you want you can do this:

```
> f3gen=function(t,a){force(t);force(a);function(c,l){foo(c,l,t,a)}}
```

Then you can create a two-parameter function with t and a set to 8 and 9 as before:

```
> f3=f3gen(8,9)
> f3(1,2)
[1] 9821
```

And this one gives us a function with them set to 8 and 6:

```
> f3=f3gen(8,6)
> f3(1,2)
[1] 6821
```

Now you've got `f3` with the values of `t` and `a` wrapped up and fixed.

However I thought `optim` always worked with a single argument vector of parameters, which means, since you've not given us a reproducible example, I've wasted my time explaining this to you.